# How to implement bitmap tile cache in Android?

Tags: android, memory

What is the best way to implement bitmap cache in Android? I can't use SoftReference, because they are nulled way too early. Currently I have a fixed cache size limit. But I still get OutOfMemoryErrors when my Activity is launched in several instances. Also, the cache size should be different for different devices.

Answer (score 0):

You should try out the [DroidFu](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/11/16/introducing-droid-fu-for-android-betteractivity-betterservice-and-betterasynctask/) class. Will take care of the cache for you.

If you want to do it yourself - use a SoftReference along with storing the image files on the SD card. Have found it to be the most effective as of now.

Comment: I can't use SoftReference, because they are nulled way too early. I have 20 bitmaps max in the cache with SoftReference and about 110 without them.

Comment: When you don't find an image through the SoftReference, you can load it from the file again. For most cases this should be enough. How many images do you have?

Comment: The tile cache is used for a map (https://market.android.com/details?id=cz.fhejl.pubtran.london). I added some numbers in my first comment. The map can have a few hundreds 256x256 tiles overall. I load bitmaps from SD card when they're not in cache - using SoftReference would de facto decrease cache size to 20 bitmaps, resulting in really bad user experience.

Comment: You don't have to keep all of them in memory all the time. Only the ones that you are displaying on the screen. Just keep track of which bitmaps will be on the screen (and probably the surrounding bitmaps) and load new ones as the map is scrolled. You can use bitmap.recycle() to free the memory of the bitmap which went out of view. You can also have a look at the NDK along with OpenGL. Might be smoother to implement it in native code. Too much of GC is a bad thing as it takes a lot of time to run the thing.

Comment: Trust me, keeping only 10 - 20 bitmaps in cache will result in worse UX. Everything is working fine with my current approach (no SoftReferences), the only thing is that I see some OutOfMemoryErrors reports. The only way I can reproduce the error is to have two instances of my Activity running.

Comment: Well, can't think of any other approach. :P